# System.Diagnostics.Process in c# and CreateProcess() in c++ which one is the best choice?

Tags: c#, c++, process

When I want to start a subProcess in my application(c#) ,`System.Diagnostics.Process` in c# and `CreateProcess()` in c++ which one is the better choice?

Give the parameters to subProcess 
Hide the subProcess's window 
Gead the subProcess's output such as logs etc.

**In addition I want to set  the CPU numbers and limit the memory for the subProcess by user.**

**I want to kill all subprocesses safely(not leak memory and some) wheb user stop the parent process**

Comment: What do you mean by "limit the memory"?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes to limit memory and CPU

Comment: That's not an answer to the question I asked. Read it again.

Answer (score 2):

`System.Diagnostics.Process` would be good. Always call managed code method from managed code.

Answer (score 1):

I guess System.Diagnostics.Process will be a good choice cause your application is managed.
if you don't want to hide the subprocess don't set :

```
the_StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
the_StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

To limit the number of cores, you have to try with `ProcessThread.ProcessorAffinity`

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ProcessThreadIdealProcessor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Make sure there is an instance of notepad running.
            Process[] notepads = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
            if (notepads.Length == 0)
                Process.Start("notepad");
            ProcessThreadCollection threads;
            //Process[] notepads; 
            // Retrieve the Notepad processes.
            notepads = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad");
            // Get the ProcessThread collection for the first instance
            threads = notepads[0].Threads;
            // Set the properties on the first ProcessThread in the collection
            threads[0].IdealProcessor = 0;
            threads[0].ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)1;
        }
    }
}
```

To limite the memory usage set `Process.MaxWorkingSet` it helps you to  the maximum allowable working set size for the associated process.